# jquery using .each with multiple selectors and knowing which one it is currenlty on

Tags: jquery, each

Sorry, this is poorly worded.

I have a .each with multiple selectors $('.class1, .class2').each(fun....
In this example is there a way to know which class it is currently iterating over within the .each.

e.g.-ILLUSTRATIVE code

```
   $('.class1, .class2').each(function () {
        var thisClass = ?$(this).iteratedClassName?;
        if ($(thisClass).prop('checked')) {
            // do something with items with thisClass assigned 
        }
    });
```

The behavior I am trying to achieve with above example is the different class names group the behavior between each class's group of elements independently of one another.

I could run the .each twice but that is not very flexible or elegant.

Comment: How something about `if($(this).hasClass("class1")){//do something}`

Comment: What's your actual goal? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to know which of the selectors it is currently iterating over.

Comment: (ran out of comment time) I need to know which of the selectors (class name) is currently being iterated over. (e.g. there may be 6 elements on the page with either class, I need the name of the class during the .each iteration. iteration 1-3 may be 'class1', 4-6 would then be 'class2'). The class names need to be flexible, as this is part of a function that will have class values passed in

Answer (score 1):

pass index and value as arguments of the anonymous function

```
$('.class1, .class2').each(function (index, value) {
    console.log(index); //which one in order you're at
    console.log(value); //value you're at
}
```

Comment: I used with $(this).val instead index, value. But it works quite good. It returns all values of all classes.

Answer (score 0):

### Get individual className(s) from a target of many

#### Snippet 1

- Use a selector that has specificity and range `('[class^="klass"]')` (Any element with a class that starts (`^`) with `klass`)
- Reference the jQuery object `this` as `self`
- Reference `self`'s classes (`classList`) [`self` is a jQuery object, so if you use a plain JavaScript method on it, we must dereference (`self[0]`).
- Display the classes.

#### Snippet 2

- Uses the `each()` method and references each element by `this`.
- The class is extracted as it is in Snippet 1.
- Upon the each iteration, each `className` is `append`ed to `#out1`.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
$('[class^="klass"]').on('click', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var cls = self[0].classList;
  $('#out1').html("Selected ClassName(s): ." + cls);
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id='kase1'>
  <div class='klass1'>KLASS1</div>
  <div class='klass2'>KLASS2</div>
  <div class='klass3'>KLASS3</div>
  <div class='klass4'>KLASS4</div>
  <div class='klass5'>KLASS5</div>
  <div class='klass6'>KLASS6</div>
  <div class='klass7'>KLASS7</div>
  <div class='klass8'>KLASS8</div>
  <div class='klass9'>KLASS9</div>
  <div class='klassA'>KLASSA</div>
  <div class='klassB'>KLASSB</div>
  <div class='klassC'>KLASSC</div>
</section>

<label for='out1'>Referencing with "this"
  <output id='out1'></output>
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
$('[class^="klass"]').each(function(obj, idx) {
  var cls = $(this)[0].classList;
  $('#out1').append("<div>ClassName: ." + cls + "</div>");
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id='kase1'>
  <div class='klass1'>KLASS1</div>
  <div class='klass2'>KLASS2</div>
  <div class='klass3'>KLASS3</div>
  <div class='klass4'>KLASS4</div>
  <div class='klass5'>KLASS5</div>
  <div class='klass6'>KLASS6</div>
  <div class='klass7'>KLASS7</div>
  <div class='klass8'>KLASS8</div>
  <div class='klass9'>KLASS9</div>
  <div class='klassA'>KLASSA</div>
  <div class='klassB'>KLASSB</div>
  <div class='klassC'>KLASSC</div>
</section>

<label for='out1'>Referencing with "this"
  <output id='out1'></output>
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
```