# How to loop Through two selected elements?

Tags: jquery

I want to loop through two classes of an `HTML` page using `jQuery` and I am trying to use each loop but the question is where can I access both of the selected classes in the callback function?

```
var href = [];

  $("div.news > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a , div.aticle  ").each((el, i) => {
      var baseURL = "someURL";
      var link = baseURL + $(i).attr("href");
      var text =
         /* i want to access text() of div.article along with the href 
           of the div.news in this loop and then push it into href array */
      href.push({
        link
      });
  });
```

I want to access the text of the **div.article** using text() function of jquery along with the `href` of **div.news** in this loop and then push it into `href` array.

Comment: You can just keep a check inside your `.each` call using `this.classList` or `$(this).is('.className')` to filter them out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery using .each with multiple selectors and knowing which one it is currenlty on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619064/jquery-using-each-with-multiple-selectors-and-knowing-which-one-it-is-currenlty)

Comment: what do you mean along with? concat??

Comment: and how's your html elements structure??

Comment: You shouldn't have `div.article` as a selector....it has no `href`.  Provide a proper explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to do, along with a [mcve] and sample of expected results

Comment: basically there is an href attribute in div.news(30 in number i.e. 30 divs) which i am able to extract out(i.e. 30 href links) of the html structure now in the same each loop i want to pull out text of div.article which is also 30 in number (i.e. 30 divs) in the same html structure and finally push both in an array upon each iteration.

Comment: which means every time when i run each loop it should push href attribute of div.news and text of div.article in an array of objects as shown in the code above

Comment: anchor tag and div.aticle  are siblings?

Comment: Don't just tell us about it....add enough basic html for us to see it and be able to run code against it. That is what is meant by a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, easier with no JQuery:

```js
var href = [];
var baseURL = "someURL";
var text, link;
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll("div.news > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a , div.article")) {
  switch (el.tagName) {
    case 'A':
      link = el.getAttribute('href');
      break;
    case 'DIV':
      text = el.textContent;
      break;
    default:
  }
};
href.push(`<a href="${baseURL}${link}">${text}</a>`);

console.log(href);
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.google.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.bing.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.duckduckgo.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="article">
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```js
var href = [];
var text = [];
$("div.news > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a, div.article").each((el, i) => {
  if ($(i).is(".article"))
    text.push($(i).text());
  else {
    var baseURL = "someURL";
    var link = baseURL + $(i).attr("href");
    href.push(link);
  }
});
console.log(href, text)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.google.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.bing.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="www.duckduckgo.com"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="article">
  text
</div>
```